# Changing social media icon color

Tags: html, css

I have a footer with some social media icons. I want to change the color of their normal state but not affect the hover state where they change color?

The site is - https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/

Can someone please tell me how to change the colors of these 4 icons so that they still change color on hover? Thanks

The code used to create this is below -

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>
                        <nav id="social-navigation" class="social-navigation">
                            <ul id="menu-social-menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-27">
                                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/FlowersForEveryoneCapeTown/" class="customize-unpreviewable">Facebook</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-33">
                                    <a href="https://twitter.com/LekkerFlowers" class="customize-unpreviewable">Twitter</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-32">
                                    <a href="https://za.pinterest.com/flowersforeveryone/" class="customize-unpreviewable">Pinterest</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-30">
                                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/flowersforeveryone_capetown/" class="customize-unpreviewable">Instagram</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <?php
```

Comment: Some code please

Comment: On this site your [mcve] code needs to be present *in* your question; linking to a live demo elsewhere (such as [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)) is a bonus, but it's not a replacement for your code being present here.

Comment: add font-awsome icons so that u can change the color and hover color easily.for ex:<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>

Comment: The problem is I can't find the code that is creating these icons - It's created in wordpress as a menu

Comment: You could just use gimp and change the color of the icons too white and reupload the images.

Comment: I updated the question with the php code that seems to create this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check this video and put the style If you need something like this:**

https://www.screenmailer.com/v/QMdg6fBKFaz8wfo

```css
.social-navigation > ul > li a[href*="facebook"]:hover {
    background-color: #4267B2;
}
.social-navigation > ul > li a[href*="twitter"]:hover {
    background-color: #38A1F2;
}
.social-navigation > ul > li a[href*="pinterest"]:hover {
    background-color: #E73E3A;
}
.social-navigation > ul > li a[href*="instagram"]:hover {
    background-color: #3f729b;
}

.content-info a, .content-info a:before {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

**If need color hover change on fontawesome icons then use this code:**

```css
.social-navigation > ul > li a[href*="facebook"]:hover:before {
    color: #4267B2 !important;
}
.social-navigation > ul > li a[href*="twitter"]:hover:before {
    color: #38A1F2 !important;
}
.social-navigation > ul > li a[href*="pinterest"]:hover:before {
    color: #E73E3A !important;
}
.social-navigation > ul > li a[href*="instagram"]:hover:before {
    color: #3f729b !important;
}
.content-info a, .content-info a:before {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. how come that works for the background color but not the font color? They are fontawesome icons??

Comment: Yes, They are fontawesome icons. If you want color change on icons then, please let me know. @Michelle

Comment: Yeah please.. I want them to be white normally and then have the color when you hover over them

Comment: @Michelle Please check the updated code in the answer, I hope need like this :)

Comment: oh perfect! Thanks so much! The only thing is now my privacy policy and terms and conditions hover it gone. It was green text on hover. How do I get this back please?

Comment: @Michelle
.footer-navigation > ul.nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #33a200 !important;
}
Please add this code and check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.content-info a, .content-info a:before {
 color: white 
 }
```

You will have to find this class `.content-info a, .content-info a:before` in the index page and then change the color.

If not, just add a custom css:

```
 .content-info a, .content-info a:before {
     color: white !important
     }
```

[image]

Comment: okay thanks. I've done that but when I put that in I lose the hover colors

Comment: The hover is still appearing when i change the colour from the DevTools :/

Comment: I can't see the hover colors at all

Comment: Can you change the colour to red and then check if the hover still shows?

Comment: it's all red now - I put this in but it doesn't work - .social-navigation > ul > li a[href*="facebook"]:hover {
    color: blue;
 
}